# Size of points in ggplot2 comparable across plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to produce various plots in which the size of a point is proportional to the number of cases that have the same values of x and y. Is there a way to make the size of the points comparable across different plots that have different values of `size`?

Example using fake data:

```
    df1 = data.frame(x = seq(1:10), 
            y = c(4,3.8,3.8,3.2,3.1,2.5,2,1.5,1.2,1.3),
            size = c(1,20,1,70,100,70,1,1,110,1))

    library(ggplot2)

    pdf("plot.1.pdf")
    ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size)) + geom_point()
    dev.off()

    df2 = data.frame(x = seq(1:10), 
            y = c(4,3.8,3.8,3.2,3.1,2.5,2,1.5,1.2,1.3),
            size = rep(1,length(y)))
    pdf("plot.2.pdf")
    ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size)) + geom_point()
    dev.off()
```

The points in Plot 1, which all have `size` equal to 1, are much larger than the points in Plot 2 for which `size` equals 1. I need a version of the plots where points with the same value of `size` have the same size across different plots. Thank you,

Sofia

Comment: In ggplot2, you deal with with this the same way as ensuring the axes are the same across plots: set the limits of the size scale.

Answer (score 16):

One possibility is to use `scale_size_identity()` - that will interpret `size` directly as units of pointsize, so in both plots points with value 1 will be the same size. But this approach will make too large points if `size` values are big (as in your case). To deal with problem of too big points, you can use transformation inside scale, for example, square root, with argument `trans="sqrt"`.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size)) + 
  geom_point()+scale_size_identity(trans="sqrt",guide="legend")

ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size)) + 
  geom_point()+scale_size_identity(trans="sqrt",guide="legend")
```

[image]

[image]

### UPDATE

As pointed out by @hadley, easiest way to achieve this is to set `limits=` inside `scale_size_continuous()` to the same values to get identical sizes.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size)) + geom_point()+
  scale_size_continuous(limits=c(1,110))
ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size)) + geom_point()+
  scale_size_continuous(limits=c(1,110))
```

[image]
[image]