# R, ggplot2: Width/size of geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a timeline with segments of different width and arbitrarily adjust the segment size.

I am using ggplot and the following data:

```
  instrument scope start_date   end_date
1          a     2 1977-01-01 1990-01-01
2          a     2 1990-01-01 1998-01-01
3          a     4 1998-01-01 2017-01-01
4          b     2 1994-01-01 1998-01-01
5          b     4 1998-01-01 2017-01-01
```

So far, I have been using the following code:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=start_date, y=instrument)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=start_date,xend=end_date,yend=instrument, size=scope))
```

The width of `geom_segment` seems to get "scaled". In other words, independently of the values by which I replace `4` in the column `scope` I get visually similar plots:

[Original plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXmPo.png)

[Plot with scope of 1000 instead of 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hxAA.png)

How could I avoid the size of the segments to be automatically "scaled" and arbitrarily increase/decrease the width of each segment?

To reproduce the dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(instrument = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), scope = c(2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L), start_date = structure(c(2557, 7305, 10227, 
8766, 10227), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(7305, 10227, 
17167, 10227, 17167), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("instrument", "scope", "start_date", 
"end_date"))
```

Comment: `+ scale_size_identity()`

Comment: @Brian If this is a not a duplicate, maybe convert your comment to an answer? Could be useful to others

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16144881/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/35281413/

Comment: Thank you @Brian, this is exactly what I was looking for.